# Find who created a table in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to identify, somewhat easily, the user that created each table in BigQuery? I've tried checking the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` but it doesn't appear that the information is in there.

---

**Update**

Just to build on the answer by Daniel below, this will get you the most recently created version of each table as well as filtering only for tables that currently exist.

```
SELECT x.* EXCEPT(is_current) 
FROM (
    SELECT destination_table.dataset_id as table_schema,
           destination_table.table_id   as table_name,
           user_email,
           creation_time,
           CASE WHEN RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY destination_table.dataset_id, 
                                              destination_table.table_id 
                                 ORDER BY creation_time DESC) = 1 THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
           END as is_current,
    FROM `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
    WHERE statement_type IN ('CREATE_TABLE', 'CREATE_TABLE_AS_SELECT')
    ORDER BY creation_time DESC) x
INNER JOIN `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES y ON x.table_schema = y.table_schema AND 
                                                      x.table_name = y.table_name
WHERE is_current = 1
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to run the following:

```
select * 
from `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
WHERE statement_type LIKE 'CREATE_TABLE%'
order by creation_time desc
;
```

The table includes the `user_email` that executed the statement. For more information on the JOBS_BY_* view here is the documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs

**UPDATE**

Based on shollyman's feedback here are some additional considerations
For tables create via a job_type of `QUERY` there are some additional statement_types you may want to look for, the list can be found here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/rest/Shared.Types/BigQueryAuditMetadata.QueryStatementType

Additionally there are other job types that are defined that can create a table.  For example scenarios where the job_type is `COPY` or `LOAD`.

The view only contains data for the past 180 days so anything beyond that you would have to persist the audit logs to either cloud storage or big query.

Comment: That will find instances of `CREATE TABLE` statements, but tables can be created from other operations: load jobs, copy jobs, SELECT statements that set an explicit destination, api requests that insert a table, etc.  Audit Logs may have additional information if you don't find what you're after in the JOBS_BY_* info schema tables: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs

Comment: I get this error Access Denied: Table europe-west2:INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query to get the details as well:

```
bq query --nouse_legacy_sql -n 1000 "
select * from DATABASE_NAME.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_name='TABLE_NAME'
"
```

Comment: I can't see a column with the name or user id of who's created the tables tho